# Reason for a reason

Tags: metaphysics

Ever since our childhood, we have been intuited to believe in an ever existing reason for everything that occurs around us. Every event that occurs has to have another event as its predicament, as it's reason. Isn't that true. We believe that everything has to have a logic associated with it...that everything must fall into the neat carpet .Those ancient rules of reasoning developed by Aristotle and the other greats have always been with us. And for so long that all of these rules now appear so natural to us...so much inculcated within us that we can bet our lives on them. These rules help us to predict a new set of propositions from a given proposition. They dictate us how to think. But the big question is that how can be so dead sure about these principles that are the foundation of this society.. and much more..of our sanity. How can we be so sure the universe lives and breaths by these fundamental principles itself. How can we be so sure about that. And much more than that, how can we say that everything occurring in the universe has to have such a reason. Why do we expect that if an event A happens in the universe than the event B most certainly cant happen as it is logically illogical? Why do we feel that the universe is any way bound? Why do we look out for a set of laws that govern the universe? Can't the universe be on a whole arbitrary and random, rather than  the ordered way we see it in our limited scope of observation.

Either the universe believes in following the monotonicity of logic and reason....or it doesn't. There cant be more that two ways about it. The second option offers it a much vast pool of possibilities and probabilities than the first one.
However let us believe in the first one. We believe in reason. We believe that every event of the universe has its consequences and it itself has a perpetuating event. Each event is caused by another event. Every reason has its own reason, the next level of explanation. But when we believe in such a symmetrical behavior..we find ourselves in crisis. The series of reasoning goes on and on. Its just like asking that what caused the universe to form, and when one finds the answer to it, we then ask him again what was the cause of the cause which lead to the formation of the universe...and on and on...And in this way, we end up with messing up with the most fundamental questions  that could ever be asked(how was the universe formed or what are the smallest entities of the universe). The only solution to this loop would an illogical halt to the series of questions. The problem with reasoning is that every reasoning proposition has to have its own reasoning proposition. Is it then necessary to search for a logical reason for everything around us?

Comment: "How can we be so sure ... ?" We can't.

Comment: And still we believe just one of the two equally poised propositions

Comment: "Can't the universe be on a whole arbitrary and random... ?" Yes, it can, **but** if the tiger will be always (or often) frustrated in its expectation that the trace of the gazelle is "caused" by the presence of the gazelle, then tigers will have disappeared long time ago.

Comment: Please explain your context. I spent the last 5 minutes trying to understand it but couldn't

Comment: We are not sure of anything, I'm afraid. However, it is **convenient** to act as if certain things were _certain_. If you had to question that your next breath of air will bring you much needed oxygen, you would live a very miserable life. In general, anything that is about the world, we fundamentally cannot be sure about. We can always question our senses for starters. Some has proposed that the only things we can be sure about are the things in our heads. Or even that only what's in our heads and immediately understood is real.

Comment: But if you do not attempt to understand the world around you in some way or another, your life will be miserable and very short. Some explanations are more efficient than others. It turns out that looking for causes and logical reasons is actually pretty efficient.